# How to disable warnings when using #pragma message?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have seen a couple of items on this, but need to use the #pragma message and have it NOT be a warning on iPhone / Xcode / compiler.

```
#pragma message("some message text")
```

results in a warning.

Yes, I could surround it with an `#ifndef` for the

```
__APPLE__
```

but that is just silly....

Any other ways to disable this warning (that work).

Answer (score -4):

The whole point of the `#pragma message` is to generate a user-defined compiler warning. If you don't want to see the warnings, comment the code out.

Comment: Doing cross development in c / c++ there are reasons / times this is wanted / needed.